# how translate it code c# to ruby (ENCODING.UTF8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, encoding

At c# I have this code

```
 private static byte[] CLAVE=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("some_string");
```

but I need in ruby it same, now How do I do it ?

right now I work with ruby 2.1.1

please I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

`CLAVE = "some_string".encode('utf-8').bytes`

But why do you want the string as an array of bytes?

Comment: because I need translate this code
            // Creamos el algoritmo encriptador
            algoritmo = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create("Rijndael");
            //Se podría haber creado el algoritmo de esta otra manera:
            //RijndaelManaged algoritmoEncriptador = new RijndaelManaged();
            ConfigurarAlgoritmo(algoritmo);
            algoritmo.Key = Clave;
            algoritmo.IV = IV;

Comment: where CLAVE and IV at c# are array of bytes and I am looking how do it.

Comment: Please don't put code in a comment. Edit your original post with more information.